# Toggle not working for material ui check boxes when printed in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

I am trying to print checkboxes of 4 per a row, where row and values of these checkboxes comes dynamically (row count may vary )

below is my jsx code

```
matrix.map((row, index) => (
                  <TableRow key={index}>
                    <TableCell align="left">
                      {row.roleDescription}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              setChecked({
                                ...checked,
                                [e.target.name]: e.target.checked,
                              })
                            }
                            name={row.roleCode + `_readAccess`}
                            checked={(e) => checked[e.target.name]}
                            color="primary"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Read"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            value={
                              row.writeAccess === null ? 0 : row.writeAccess
                            }
                            onChange={(e) => {}}
                            name="readAccess"
                            color="primary"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Write"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            value={
                              row.checkerAccess === null
                                ? 0
                                : row.checkerAccess
                            }
                            onChange={(e) =>
                              setMatrixForm({
                                ...setMatrixForm,
                                checkerAccess: e.target.checked,
                              })
                            }
                            checked={
                              row.writeAccess &&
                              row.writeAccess !== "" &&
                              row.writeAccess === 1
                                ? true
                                : false
                            }
                            name="checkerAccess"
                            color="primary"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Checker"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="right">
                      <FormControlLabel
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            checked={
                              row.readAccess &&
                              row.readAccess !== "" &&
                              row.readAccess === 1
                                ? true
                                : false
                            }
                            name="readAccess"
                            color="primary"
                          />
                        }
                        label="Maker"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
```

After fetching the `matix` data I am setting state variable `const[checked, setChecked] = useState([])`
as below

```
.then((rec) => {
    if (rec.status === 200) {
      let chk = [];

      rec.data.data.map((item, idx) => {
        var obj = {};
        obj[item.roleDescription + `_readAccess`] = item.readAccess;
        chk.push(obj);
        obj[item.roleDescription + `_writeAccess`] = item.writeAccess;
        chk.push(obj);
        obj[item.roleDescription + `_checkerAccess`] = item.checkerAccess;
        chk.push(obj);
        obj[item.roleDescription + `_makerAccess`] = item.makerAccess;
        chk.push(obj);
      });

      setChecked(chk);



    }
  })
```

what I have tried, is since my rows which are changing dynamically I created `state` variable entries with as `rowName + one of check box label` , so when `onChange` triggered on CheckBox it should change the state and check box need to be toggeled.

but Check box are not getting toggled,

**EDIT ADDED SAMPLE SNIPPED in CODESANDBOX**
[sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-microservice-eqgh8?file=/src/Demo.jsx)

Pelse help.
thx

Comment: `checked` is a boolean on `Checkbox`. Have a look here: https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#props

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: @NishargShah hello, hi I have added as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `=== 1 ? false : true` from `checked` because in `onChange` you are setting `boolean`

```
setChecked({
    ...checked,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
})
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-paper-lvcwe?file=/src/Demo.jsx

**EDIT 1**

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log("checked called");
}, [checked]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got this myself too, but the thing is I have been storing all these checkbox states in `checked` state variable as `array`, so when checkbox onChange event triggered, I want to change the value for that particular Item, I find quite difficult to do that

Comment: use `useEffect` and check `condition` if `checked[row.roleCode + `_readAccess`]` then do something and don't forgot to add dependency [checked]

Comment: but, `useEffect` is happening at the time of rendering, I actually need to set State variables at the time of `onChange ` event on `checkBox`

Comment: as I said add the dependency of checked, so every time when the checkbox value changed, useEffect will call

Comment: Sorry, my bad would you mind to edit my snadbox ?

Comment: I added console log, when every time checked array changed, please look it